# setting up MariaDB Galera cluster Ubuntu Zesty

Tags: ubuntu, mariadb, galera

I can't figure out how to initialize a MariaDB Galera cluster on Ubuntu Zesty.  I've followed the documentation, but something seems to be missing.  I cannot get the first node to come up.

I installed using standard package:

```
apt install mariadb-server
```

I've configured the cluster in `/etc/mysql/mariadb.conf.d/90-cluster.cnf`

```
[mariadb]
bind-address = 0.0.0.0
binlog-format = ROW
innodb-autoinc-lock-mode = 2
innodb-flush-log-at-trx-commit = 0
wsrep-on = ON
wsrep-sst-method = rsync
wsrep-cluster-name = "example"
wsrep-cluster-address = "gcomm://maria01.example.com,maria02.example.com"
wsrep-node-address = "maria01"
wsrep-node-name = "maria01.example.com"
```

> Note: I've also attempted setting the wsrep-cluster-address to "gcomm://"

I attempt to bootstrap by stopping the service and starting with the specialized script:

```
systemctl stop mariadb
galera_new_cluster
```

Then I connect to the instance and check the status:

```
show global variables like 'wsrep%';
+---------------------------------+-----------------------------------------+
| wsrep_osu_method                | TOI                                     |
| wsrep_auto_increment_control    | ON                                      |
| wsrep_causal_reads              | OFF                                     |
| wsrep_certify_nonpk             | ON                                      |
| wsrep_cluster_address           | gcomm://                                |
| wsrep_cluster_name              | example                                 |
| wsrep_convert_lock_to_trx       | OFF                                     |
| wsrep_data_home_dir             | /var/lib/mysql/                         |
| wsrep_dbug_option               |                                         |
| wsrep_debug                     | OFF                                     |
| wsrep_desync                    | OFF                                     |
| wsrep_dirty_reads               | OFF                                     |
| wsrep_drupal_282555_workaround  | OFF                                     |
| wsrep_forced_binlog_format      | NONE                                    |
| wsrep_gtid_domain_id            | 0                                       |
| wsrep_gtid_mode                 | OFF                                     |
| wsrep_load_data_splitting       | ON                                      |
| wsrep_log_conflicts             | OFF                                     |
| wsrep_max_ws_rows               | 0                                       |
| wsrep_max_ws_size               | 2147483647                              |
| wsrep_mysql_replication_bundle  | 0                                       |
| wsrep_node_address              | maria01                                 |
| wsrep_node_incoming_address     | AUTO                                    |
| wsrep_node_name                 | maria01.example.com                     |
| wsrep_notify_cmd                |                                         |
| wsrep_on                        | OFF                                     |
| wsrep_patch_version             | wsrep_25.16                             |
| wsrep_provider                  | none                                    |
| wsrep_provider_options          | pc.bootstrap=1                          |
| wsrep_recover                   | OFF                                     |
| wsrep_replicate_myisam          | OFF                                     |
| wsrep_restart_slave             | OFF                                     |
| wsrep_retry_autocommit          | 1                                       |
| wsrep_slave_fk_checks           | ON                                      |
| wsrep_slave_uk_checks           | OFF                                     |
| wsrep_slave_threads             | 1                                       |
| wsrep_sst_auth                  |                                         |
| wsrep_sst_donor                 |                                         |
| wsrep_sst_donor_rejects_queries | OFF                                     |
| wsrep_sst_method                | rsync                                   |
| wsrep_sst_receive_address       | AUTO                                    |
| wsrep_start_position            | 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000:-1 |
| wsrep_sync_wait                 | 0                                       |
+---------------------------------+-----------------------------------------+

show status like 'wsrep%';
+--------------------------+----------------------+
| wsrep_cluster_conf_id    | 18446744073709551615 |
| wsrep_cluster_size       | 0                    |
| wsrep_cluster_state_uuid |                      |
| wsrep_cluster_status     | Disconnected         |
| wsrep_connected          | OFF                  |
| wsrep_local_bf_aborts    | 0                    |
| wsrep_local_index        | 18446744073709551615 |
| wsrep_provider_name      |                      |
| wsrep_provider_vendor    |                      |
| wsrep_provider_version   |                      |
| wsrep_ready              | ON                   |
| wsrep_thread_count       | 0                    |
+--------------------------+----------------------+
```

Note especially the `wsrep_cluster_size`, which is 0, but it should be 1 after running `galera_new_cluster` according to the documentation.

The Maria log doesn't have a whole lot, but it does seem like the cluster is initialized:

```
systemd[1]: Starting MariaDB database server...
sh[4083]: 2017-05-03 22:11:40 139734663651904 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 10.1.22-MariaDB-) starting as process 4203 ...
sh[4083]: WSREP: Recovered position 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000:-1
mysqld[4238]: 2017-05-03 22:11:44 140634874606144 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 10.1.22-MariaDB-) starting as process 4238 ...
systemd[1]: Started MariaDB database server.
```

Comment: I'm assuming your node names are resolvable by the server, or else that may be the issue.  MariaDB generally has good logging, are you getting any errors in the logs?

Comment: The node names are resolvable.  I've added the log output to the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your cluster configuration is missing a few things:

1. `wsrep_provider` should be set to the path to the Galera wsrep library
2. `wsrep_on` should be set to "ON".

It looks like you actually need to modify most of the configuration to use underscores rather than dashes.  The key issues in your status output is that there is no `wsrep_provider` and that `wsrep_on` is set to off.  You can see the mandatory configuration settings on the [MariaDB page](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/getting-started-with-mariadb-galera-cluster/#configuration-and-monitoring).

Comment: After adding wsrep_provider, the wsrep_on setting took affect, and everything looks good.  Thanks!